# sympy: how to sympify logical "NOT"

Tags: python, sympy

The following code would work to sympify logical expressions:

```
sympify('a&b') # And(a, b)
sympify('a|b') # Or(a, b)
```

But how do I get a result of `Not(a)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the symbol you are looking for is `~`.  See the following:

```
>>> from sympy import sympify
>>> sympify('a&b')
And(a, b)
>>> sympify('a|b')
Or(a, b)
>>> sympify('~a')
Not(a)
```